# Need help revising a simple formula to make it universal

Tags: java, trigonometry

I am trying to perform a calculation for my program that will allow me to have each letter rotated to face towards the center coordinates of a circle....

The number of characters I am working with is 16 but I want this algorithm to work with any number of letters wrapping around a circle of any size, the positions of the letters have already been set within a loop that places them in the correct positions.

```
The formula I have goes something like this
degree = 360 / phrase.length() -> where phrase.length() is 16
rotate = 360 / (phrase.length() - degree

This is where I set the rotation
degrees = degree
Letter.setRotate((degrees + rotate) - (205));
degrees = degrees + degree
the next letter is then set using the Letter.setRotate((degrees + rotate) - (205)
this goes on and on until each letter is printed and rotated
```

Using the above formula the letters print out facing the center, but what is a better way of doing this that will allow me to use this for an unknown phrase length?

Below is the loop that I have created so far, even without programming experience you may be able to understand most of it...at least equation portions

```
// Place text in a circular pattern
int i = 0;
double degree = 360 / phrase.length(), rotate = 360 / (phrase.length() - degree);
Font font = new Font("Times Roman", textSize);
for (double degrees = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++, degrees += degree) {
    double pointX = circle.getCenterX() + circle.getRadius() *
        Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees));
    double pointY = circle.getCenterY() + circle.getRadius() *
        Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees));
    Text letter = new Text(pointX, pointY, phrase.charAt(i) + "");
    letter.setFont(font);
    letter.setRotate((degrees + rotate) - (205));
    getChildren().add(letter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright figured it out :)

I didn't even need rotate what I did was get the current degrees for that letter and add 90 to it...Apparently I was overcomplicating it

Here is the working loop

```
// Place text in a circular pattern
int i = 0;
double degree = 360 / phrase.length();
Font font = new Font("Times Roman", textSize);
for (double degrees = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++, degrees += degree) {
    double pointX = circle.getCenterX() + circle.getRadius() *
        Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees));
    double pointY = circle.getCenterY() + circle.getRadius() *
        Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees));
    Text letter = new Text(pointX, pointY, phrase.charAt(i) + "");
    letter.setFont(font);
    letter.setRotate(degrees + 90);
    getChildren().add(letter);
}
```